# How can I do volume mapping (mounting volumes) in dock:dind in GitLab CI?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, selenium-grid, docker-volume

I am trying to run a [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) download test in GitLab CI. I use *docker:dind* in the *gitlab-ci.yml* file. The test failed because of no files being really downloaded. What should I do?

The test script:

```
package seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginTest_chrome_ci {
    WebDriver driver;
    File folder;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws  MalformedURLException {

        String directory = "/target";
        folder = new File(directory);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
        prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", "true");
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", folder.getAbsolutePath());

        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://docker:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

    }

    @Test
    public void downloadFileTest() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/download");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("some-file.txt")).click();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        File listOffFiles[] = folder.listFiles();

        System.out.println(listOffFiles.length);
        Assert.assertTrue(listOffFiles.length > 0);

        for(File file : listOffFiles) {
            Assert.assertTrue(file.length() > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In the *docker-compose* file, I have done the volume mapping for the Chrome container:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: chrome
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    volumes:
      - /target:/home/seluser/Downloads
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

And the *gitlab-ci.yml* file I use is:

```
image: adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

stages:
  - gradle-build
  - docker-test

.gradle_template: &gradle_definition
  variables:
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.gradle

gradle-build:
  <<: *gradle_definition
  stage: gradle-build
  script:
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew --build-cache assemble
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
    - feature/multi-browsers

chrome-test:
  stage: docker-test
  image:
    name: docker/compose:1.29.2
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  dependencies:
    - gradle-build
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker-compose --version
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - apk add openjdk11
    - mkdir /target
    - chmod -R 777 /target
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps -d
    - echo "Hello, chrome-test"
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew :test --tests "LoginTest_chrome_ci"

  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/**/TEST-*.xml
    paths:
      - build/reports/*
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
    - feature/multi-browsers

after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

The error I got is:

```
Gradle suite > Gradle test > seleniumTest.LoginTest_chrome_ci > downloadFileTest FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at LoginTest_chrome_ci.java:71
```

Comment: Let's start with what was output in the log for this line of code `System.out.println(listOffFiles.length);`

Comment: That's a problem to me. I don't know where to see the output  in gitlab CI. :(  It is showed only in intellij when i run it locally.

Comment: Are you running this via an organisation gitlab instance? If so you, you might have access to the UI. If you go to the project in question, look for CICD in the left hand sidebar and see if you can access your job run

Comment: I don't get what you mean here. I can access to the 'Jobs' under CI/CD on the left side of the project.  But can not find any console output of the test script.  The test result output showed in the job just shows like if the building is succeed or fail.

Comment: Can you click on that result and se if it takes you to anything internally or externally ?

Comment: I may download the job artifact. But inside it cannot find something useful. It has these:       java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:96)
 at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:776)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:44)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
 at seleniumTest.LogInTest_chrome.downloadFileTest(LogInTest_chrome.java:68)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: ok - now that it is linux vm => docker = chrome node, update docker-compose mapping to `- /target:/target` - see if it passes the absolute path correctly to the browser

Comment: Hej, I haved try it (- /target:/target) in the pipeline just now. I got the error: NullPointerException.

Comment: Hey, I'm back. Read everything below, seen you are using selenium-grid v4. The new version has been designed with a redirect for calls to `http://<selenium-grid-host>:4444/wd/hub` to be redirected to the this new grid connection `http://<selenium-grid-host>:4444`, so that it was backward compatible for previous projects that used selenium-grid v3. I am thinking that the redirect (HTTP 302) may be restricted in the environment. So update the LoginTest_chrome_ci.java method to the following: `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://docker:4444"), cap);` - lets see if that works

Comment: Hej, just see your comment. And thanks again for your try. I tried, and it worked like the same as "http://docker:4444/wd/hub", got the assertionError.  and I also tried it with addind a extra file foo.txt with permission "- chown 1200:1201 ./target", and the same, could not connect to the remote url.

Comment: Hey, did you get this resolved ?

Comment: Hello, not yet. I used another way to verify the downloaded file, but not via the mounting volumes.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar issue with a Docker runner and Docker-in-Docker by just changing a couple of values of `config.toml` (as indicated in [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41227)):

1. Set `privileged = true`
2. Add `"/builds:/builds"` to `volumes`

Answer (score 0):

With `docker:dind` service, volume mapping with docker-compose works more or less as per normal.

I would recommend using a relative path, however, instead of an absolute path in the root. e.g. `./target` instead of `/target`.

### Mounting a directory with docker:dind

As a minimal reproducible example of this:

Take the following compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello > /opt/data/foo.txt"]
    volumes:
      - ./target:/opt/data
```

This will create a single container with a mount point at the *relative* directory `./target` and mount it to `/opt/data` in the container.
When the service container starts, it will simply create a file `/opt/data/foo.txt` with the text `hello`.

And the following gitlab CI yaml:

```yaml
test:
  image: docker/compose
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - ls # no target directory exists
    - docker-compose up
    - ls target  # target directory was created and foo.txt exists
    - cat ./target/foo.txt  # see the contents of foo.txt as "hello"
```

Therefore, your error must be the result of something other than the mount point not mounting your directory.

### Permissions considerations

File/directory permissions still apply to bind mounts. So, the user in the container needs permission to read/write the mounted directory/files.

The problem you *are* almost certainly experiencing in this case is that the user in your `selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-20211013` docker container has a UID/GID of `1200`/`1201`. Therefore, the directory that's created in your job by `docker-compose` for the volume mount won't be writable by the user in the container.

For instance, the same minimal example above -- the job would fail with a "permission denied" error if the image were changed from `busybox`(which runs as root, same as the job container) to `selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-20211013`, which runs with a different user UID/GID.

Therefore, it can be concluded that your issue is that Chrome is unable to write to the `~/Downloads` directory and that's why you're not seeing the files in the downloads directory.

### How to fix your issue

To remedy this, you should create the mount point ahead of time `chown` it to the uid/gid of the user in the container.

So two things:

1. Change the directory to `./target` instead of `/target` (update compose file and your code)
2. in your GitLab-CI job, pre-create `./target` and `chown 1200:1201 ./target` before starting docker-compose

Something like this will resolve the permissions issue:

```yaml
before_script:
  - mkdir -p ./target
  - chown 1200:1201 ./target
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. But it still got the same result 'AssertionError' after I did what you have mentioned above. I understand it would be a permission problem and now I am also think about how can i set the shared path in gitlab-ci. yml, docker compose file and the test script according to this post: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41227.

Comment: @AutoBeginner the example I showed demonstrates how to do mounting correctly. The container has access to the `./target` directory in the build workspace mounted inside the container as `/opt/data`. If the container writes to `/opt/data/abc` it will show up in the build directory as `./target/abc`. Does that help?  -- The concerns in the issue you mention are muddled with a lot of irrelevant discussion and deal mostly with `docker run` which works slightly differently than `docker-compose`. If you are still getting an AssertionError, it is likely for some reason other than the volume mount.

Comment: Hej, thanks. I have tried to do: I put this "entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello > /home/seluser/Downloads/foo.txt"]" in the docker-compose file for the chorme image, and now in the output of the pipeline, I saw the file "foo.txt" in the folder 'target'. That's great. But when running the test,  it came accross the timeout problem at this line: driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("docker:4444/wd/hub"), cap); It seems that it cannot to connect to the docker dind host after i add entrypoint to the chrome image.

Comment: what could be the reason? could it verify the volume mount is correct? That the same when running locally with "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub". I could see the foo.txt in the 'target', but it turned out to be "invalid address of the remote server" when ran the test.

Comment: @AutoBeginner sounds like the subject of another question.

Comment: So  I just added a file into the folder before running the test. and the volume mount really worked. But I cannot understand why there is matters with connecting to the remote url.