# Cant run integration tests with docker compose in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, integration-testing

I have a Node.js application that connects to a Postgres database and I have made some integration tests and want to launch them in the Gitlab CI pipeline using docker-compose.

I have containerized the app and made a docker-compose file and everything works fine locally.
Now I want to execute the `docker-compose up` command in the Gitlab ci pipeline with the shared runners.

**I tried:**

1 - The DinD solution in the [gitlab ci documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker).

2 - Changing different versions of docker.

3 - This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868369/run-docker-compose-build-in-gitlab-ci-yml).

**Problem:**

The pipeline fails at the `docker info` command with the following error:

**Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose.yml`, `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` files with us, please?

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071016/how-to-setup-gitlab-ci-e2e-tests-using-multiple-dockers/69955434#69955434

Comment: @Dennis Sorry it was a long time ago and I forgot how we did exacty but all I remember is that we used custom gitlab runner for our job.